# Stellaris game via steam runs super slow (3 fps in menu)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games

I have a top of the line machine that runs Stellaris blazingly fast on windows, but on Ubuntu 18.04 stellaris runs SUPER slow like it's not even using the graphics card. I am using nvidia card.

Saw this in dmesg, not sure if it's related. My guess is it's unrelated since it seems to have happened in less than a second?:

```
[  193.532941] powercap intel-rapl:0: package locked by BIOS, monitoring only
[  194.574036] CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574037] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574039] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574043] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574044] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574045] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574046] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574047] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574048] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.574057] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  194.575038] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[  194.575039] CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
[  194.575040] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[  194.575041] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[  194.575042] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[  194.575043] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[  194.575044] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[  194.575045] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[  194.575045] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[  194.575046] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[  201.541002] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
[  227.457422] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
[  231.461084] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
[  235.464786] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
[  239.468445] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
[  256.793728] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
```

Comment: I'd bet that your computer renders using either the CPU alone or the integrated GPU inside your CPU, both of which heat up the CPU, giving the `temperature above threshold` messages above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed the latest nVidia drivers (Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > nVidia) or `sudo apt install nvidia-current`

But then when I rebooted everything went black, because I'm on an Optimus card (hybrid nvidia/intel GPU for laptop powersaving) so I installed prime:
`sudo apt install nvidia-prime` and set the correct GPU via `nvidia-settings` (it was on Intel)
and rebooted again and everything worked great! Game ran great!